# ¿Cómo configurar las reglas de un proyecto de Firebase para que sea seguro?

Tags: base-de-datos, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, realtime-database

Tengo el proyecto *Firebase* y cuando creo las bases de datos, creo algunas reglas para las pruebas. Ahora caducan y cierran mi proyecto. Es la primera vez que trabajo con proyectos de *Firebase* y no tengo experiencia. Les muestro cómo he definido las reglas tanto para *Cloud Firestore* como para *Realtime Database*.

El proyecto es una aplicación *React Native* en la que los usuarios pueden registrarse y dejar sus comentarios.

- ¿Cómo debo establecer las reglas para que mis bases de datos sean seguras?
- ¿Cómo debo escribir mi código de reglas?

Estuve ausente de mi proyecto unos días y me escribieron desde Google, que cierra mi proyecto en dos días. He buscado información, pero no sé cómo crear las reglas para que sean correctas y mi proyecto también funcione.

En mi aplicación solo quiero que los usuarios registrados puedan escribir comentarios.

La alerta que me muestra *Firebase* es la siguiente:

> "Sus reglas de seguridad están definidas como públicas, por lo que cualquiera puede robar, modificar o borrar datos de su base de datos".

Las bases de datos están vacías, por lo que aún no hay registros.

¿Me pueden ayudar? ***Firebase* cerrará mi proyecto si no escribo las reglas correctamente, las reglas no deberían ser públicas.**

Leí la [documentación que ofrece Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#allow-all) , pero realmente no entiendo cómo crear mis reglas.

He visto algún otro caso, pero no entiendo como hacerlas, he puesto las reglas en *Cloud Firestore* de esta forma, pero parece que tampoco son seguras:

```
rules_version = '2';
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Las reglas de *Realtime Database* son las siguientes:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Es muy cómodo de mi parte pedir ayuda para que me ayuden a escribir el código de mis reglas, pero realmente por más que re-leo [la documentación Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions), no logro entender. Incluso he visto algún tutorial.

Si pueden ayudarme, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

las reglas que mencionas ahi estaño bien "allow read, write: if request.auth != null;"  básicamente le dices que estas permitiendo que solo entren y escriban los que están firmados.   ¿qué hay de malo con eso?

¿si activaste y publicaste esas reglas?

Comment: Convendría para que tu respuesta sea mas completa tal vez le expliques lo relacionado a la pregunta final que haces